# Why does JS code stop working when saved in an external file in the Play Framework

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework, google-visualization

I'm currently refactoring my `myFile.scala.html` within the PlayFramework.

JS as **inline code** correctly returns a google chart with data:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() { 
...

};
```

But returns an empty chart when imported as a separate .js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/javascripts", "myChart.js")"></script>
```

My route looks like this:

```
GET     /javascripts/*file          controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/javascripts", file)
```

The fact that an empty chart is rendered suggests that it reads the JS fine, but doesn't read the data. Why doesn't it read the data?

--

ETA - @AndriyKuba, here is the JS code that was extracted that you asked for:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'dateTime');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
      var mapString = "@map";
      var pairsArray = mapString.split(",");
      pairsArray.forEach(function(pair) {
      ...
      data.addRows([[dateString, count]]);
      });
      var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('myChart_div'));
      var Slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
          ...
          }
        });
        var barCh = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            ...
          }
        });
      dashboard.bind(Slider, barCh);
      google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, 'ready', onReady);
        dashboard.draw(data);

        function onReady() {
            google.visualization.events.addListener(barCh.getChart(), 'select', selectHandler);

            function selectHandler(e){
                window.location.href='/mydata/' + data.getValue(barCh.getChart().getSelection()[0].row, 0);
            };
        }
  }
```

my scala variables at the top of the .scala.html file:

```
@(count: Int, schCount: Int, list: List[String], myVariable: String, apiSelector: List[String], map: Map[String, Integer])
```

My data is on a mongoDB and is read in as a java List Object. Like I said, the exact same syntax works inline, but not linked from a separate js file.
I suspect it's the scala variable, and I've tried to introduce a global variable inline and reference that in the JS file, but that so far hasn't worked for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the end. It wasn't a routing problem, as I suspected all along. I introduced a global variable for the scala reference to my map ("@map") in the html head:

```
<script>
window.APP = {map: '@map'};
</script>
```

and called it within the main chart function:

```
function drawChart() {
  var map = window.APP.map;
  ...
  var mapString = map;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did check, it works.

You have an issue with the router here, `javascript` folder is doubled.

```
GET     /javascripts/*file          controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Then use assets as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myChart.js")"></script>
```

**Update**

My controller:

```
val chartData = """[
        ['Michael' , 5],
        ['Elisa', 7],
        ['Robert', 3],
        ['John', 2],
        ['Jessica', 6],
        ['Aaron', 1],
        ['Margareth', 8]
      ]"""

Ok(views.html.charts(chartData))
```

My `charts.scala.html`:

```
@(chartData: String)

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/charts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var myData = @Html(chartData);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `charts.js`:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'dateTime');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
  data.addRows(myData);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var Slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'filter_div',
      'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Count'
      }
    });

  var barCh = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',
      'options': {
          'width': 300,
          'height': 300,
          'pieSliceText': 'value',
          'legend': 'right'
      }
    });

  dashboard.bind(Slider, barCh);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

The result:

[image: dashboard]

Comment: Sadly that's not it. I don't think it's routing related, since the page and empty google charts loads in. It's just my chart data that's missing, but loaded when JS was inline.

Comment: I take the JS code, from this example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

Put it in the external js file, then create an HTML page and load this file on that page - and it's work. So it looks, like you have some issue with routes or some misprint in your code.  Can you add all JS code ? (or the part that reproduce the issue)

Comment: hard coded items load in, @AndriyKuba. it's the dynamic data that doesn't make it. In my case a java List Object for a table and a java Map Object for the google chart. I tried setting up a global variable inline and calling it in the JS, but am struggling with making that work.

Comment: You could not use dynamic variables in assets. So you need to put the dynamic variables on the page or load them by calling to the API. 

I see that you use `var mapString = "@map"` in the script - that will not work in the asset. Put it on the page (twirl template) and all dynamic data that you have.

Comment: Ok. I've introduced a global variable to the html head and am calling it in the JS. Console reads the data, but the chart doesn't pick it up.

Comment: I did some example on the base of your code - it works perfectly, so look for some missprint in your code.

Comment: Static data wasn't the problem. It was the dynamic data loaded by a scala variable from within the play framework that wouldn't load it when imported from the external JS file. I had a syntax error with the global variable to begin with. After sorting that out, it loads perfectly. Check my answer above. Thanks for your help @AndriyKuba

Comment: lol, I wrote completely the same as you did `var myData = @Html(chartData);`